# Underscore.js - filtering in a nested Json

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I want to get all values, where the category.id = 1 so i should get 2 results

My JSON looks like this:

```
var test = [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "name1",
                "value": "value1",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "category1"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "name2",
                "value": "value2",
                "category": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "category1"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "name3",
                "value": "value3",
                "category": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "category2"
                }
            }
        ];
```

my JavaScript looks like this:

```
var x = _.filter(test,
            function (innerObject) {
                return _.filter(innerObject,
                    function (category) {
                        return  category.id === 1;
                    });
            });

console.log(x);
```

[I made a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6AnC/) but i get everytime all 3 elements back... not only the 2 correct ones!

I tried also something like

```
var x = _.where(test, {"category":{"id":2}});
console.log(x);
```

what seems to be logical for me, but the array is always empty

[another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cv6Bu/)

I hope somebody can tell me what i made wrong...
Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because with where you're searching for an element that is EXACTLY like `{"category":{"id":1}}` and your object is `{"category":{"id":1,"name":"category1"}}`

Try

```
_.filter(test, function(a){ return a.category && a.category.id === 1; });
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
var x = test.filter(function (a) {return a.category.id === 1 })
```

Comment: it's working... but i prefer the coding-style of pesta.
but perfect would be the answer of both:
    `var x = _.filter(test,function (a) {return a.category.id === 1 });`