# Nested Category Search using underscore js

Tags: arrays, json, underscore.js, lodash

This is how my data object would look like [http://jsfiddle.net/303tpLtz/1](http://jsfiddle.net/303tpLtz/)

As you may see [here](https://gist.github.com/sahanDissanayake/b29c913a00d33bffc67f#file-gistfile1-js-L199) there are categories inside categories which must be considered when the search is done

So the problem is I can find the top level names of the categories using `_.findWhere(result.response.categories, {name: 'Arts & Entertainment'})`

But the problem is when I need to find something mentioned inside the supplied request, For example if I need to find a restaurant which is inside Food >

Can anyone help me with the Deep search function please ?

My tangled solution [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yw15utn/5):

```
function findDeep(cats, attrs) {
    _.each(cats, function(data, i) {
        var copy = data;
        // delete copy.categories;
        newArr.push(copy);
        _.each(data.categories, function(newObj) {
            var copy2 = newObj;
            // delete copy2.categories;
            newArr.push(copy2)

            if (newObj.categories) {
                _.each(newObj.categories, function(otherObj) {
                    var copy3 = otherObj;
                    // delete copy3.categories;
                    newArr.push(copy3)
                })
            }
        })
    });

    return _.findWhere(newArr, attrs) || null;
}
```

Comment: guess: [Underscore.js - filtering in a nested Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994658/underscore-js-filtering-in-a-nested-json). Internet search: _`Underscore.js - filtering in a nested Json`_. are more guesses

Comment: No @RyanVincent, If you look close please, there are more json objects inside my categories that needs considered when the search is done https://gist.github.com/sahanDissanayake/b29c913a00d33bffc67f#file-gistfile1-js-L199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this data is each node potentially should be inspected further, which means you can't neatly apply a filter to every item, because the skipped items themselves might have nested categories you need to inspect.

However, using plain javascript or alternatively with the help of [_.reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) and a bit of [recursive magic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx), we can get the job done with only a little bit of code.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/7yw15utn/6/)

```
function findMatchingCategories(cats, attrs) {
    return _.filter(extractCategories(cats), attrs);

    function extractCategories(cats) {
        return _.reduce(cats, function (result, value) {
            return result.concat([value]).concat(value.categories ? extractCategories(value.categories) : []);
        }, []);
    }
}

console.log(findMatchingCategories(data, { name: 'Tunnel' }));
```

To explain:

`_.reduce` let's you go through a set of data and keep track of a progressively 'reduced' data variable. In our case, we reduce a set of categories to a new array called `result` which only contains all nested categories. To make sure we inspect all nested categories as well, we recursively call `extractCategories` and use it's result to add it to the reduced result array.

Finally what we are left with are all categories, nested or not, which we then filter based on `attr` matches.

---

A more performant version with less concatenation:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/7yw15utn/7/)

```
function findMatchingCategories(cats, attrs) {
    return _.filter(extractCategories(cats, []), attrs);

    function extractCategories(currentCats, allCats) {
        _.each(currentCats, function (value) {
            allCats.push(value);
            if (value.categories) {
                extractCategories(value.categories, allCats);
            }
        }, []);
        return allCats;
    }
}

console.log(findMatchingCategories(data, { name: 'Tunnel' }));
```

The more we go for performance, the less concise the code becomes.

[Performance comparison of all three approaches](http://jsperf.com/recursive-vs-fixed-lodash/2)

Comment: hey, Im using lodash V2.4.1 https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2.4.1/doc/README.md The _.isMatch is not there, Anything else that i could use ?

Comment: I thought you were using underscore... did you switch? Anyway, it's still possible to use `_.where` or `_.filter` instead of `_.isMatch`. I updated my answer.

Comment: seems like my function is super fast than yours ?!?!? http://jsfiddle.net/a3wevt35/4/

Comment: It seems it's more time consuming to filter many small arrays than it is to filter one big array. I updated my answer with a shorter and faster version. It is still slower. However, unless you have a performance issue, don't engage in [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)!

Comment: im quite worried about performance since this function will be executes in a NodeJS server, so faster the better i guess

Comment: It seems concatenating slows down the process as well. I returned to an approach similar to yours (using `_.each`), but still applying recursion. Here's [the performance of all three approaches](http://jsperf.com/recursive-vs-fixed-lodash/2).